# Add a String to a textView but change its color

Tags: android, layout, textview

I looked in the forums for an answer and I tried doing it but for some reason the color is not changing, is there anything im doing wrong ?

```
SpannableString wordtoSpan = new SpannableString(songSelected);
        wordtoSpan.setSpan(
             new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)),
             wordtoSpan.length()-1, 
             wordtoSpan.length(), 
             Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        selected_song.setText("Selected song is: "+ wordtoSpan);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
String styledText = "This is <font color='red'>simple</font>.";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```